# Box2D : Angry Bird like Pulley System

Tags: box2d, box2d-iphone

I got  one requirement something similar to Angry bird  game like pulley system. Which box2d joint is good enough for this elastic pulley in Angry bird game? Any example with texture? or any online sample with elastic moving body?

(ANGRY BIRD, Bird droping pulley..any similar example with code?)

Updates: Just wondering is that new apple game engine 'Sprite Kit' support this kind of real physics?

Comment: question about "elastic rope joint": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9171937/box2d-elastic-rope-joint

Comment: @Thilo, Thank you Sir, but m not getting actual output. Is there any sample with texture of elastic rope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some clone of angry birds are using [Space Manager](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/archives/1214),another one is [Ghetto Birds](http://highoncoding.com/Articles/858_Implementing_Ghetto_Birds_Part_1.aspx) and another best example is here in [ReyWenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4756/how-to-make-a-catapult-shooting-game-with-cocos2d-and-box2d-part-1) 
For Pulling your Pulley you need this method:

```
 -(void)draw
```

and then draw two lines of using

```
ccDrawLine(ccp(source.position.x,source.position.y), ccp(destinition.position.x,destinition.position.y));
```

Hope Its help you a lot.