# How do I connect 2 ropes to a hanging sign using Box2d?

Tags: box2d

I'm using the code from this question/answer and it works perfectly: [Box2d elastic rope joint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9171937/box2d-elastic-rope-joint)

The code iterates using a FOR loop to create the rope joints.  I am trying to get it to hang a sign and swing naturally.  I created a second FOR loop and this works.  I now have 2 swinging ropes!

My question is, how do I connect the end of each rope to the sign (rectangle sprite)?

I've managed to get it to connect to the second rope, last fixture (since these are the natural values after the FOR loop has run its course) and it's working great, only the first rope is not connected to the sign.  I need to be able to find out what the last joint/body is of the 1rst rope so that I can then connect it (joint) to the sign object...so I'm really asking is how to find the last joint/body of the 1rst rope (i.e. first FOR loop)?

Comment: Just looking at that question you linked to, if you need to have a springy rope with a hard limit max distance, it would probably be easier to use both a rope joint and a distance joint together. Make the distance of the rope joint a bit longer than the distance joint.

Comment: The code from the previous question includes both rope and distance joints so am not clear on your comment.

Comment: Hi Jim! Sorry, I did not read that answer fully - it looks ok. I would just point out though that it's not really necessary to have more than one rope joint per chain.